# jQuery grid plugin - js and css path

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

In the how to install section of the jQuery Grid plugin, it is said:

> Step 3: Under the myproject folder,
>   create two additional directories
>   named js and css

Are these names a suggestion or a strong restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are suggestions.  You will specify the locations of the js file and the css files within your HTML.

Comment: I know I will, I was just wondering if there were any hard coded restriction within the jqgrid code. Apparently not, then..

Comment: @Rodrigo Gama: the only place with any path exist in Development Installation exist and documented on the same page http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install#development_installation: "open the grid.loader.js file and change the pathtojsfiles variable to “js/src/”". If you use minimized version of jqGrid: **jquery.jqGrid.min.js** then there are no file/directory referenced  within the code.